# Is there a standard order for the X.509 extensions of a certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, x.509

Is there a standard order for the X.509 extensions of a certificate?

For example:

```
 [ myca_extensions ]
 basicConstraints = critical,CA:FALSE
 keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
 extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
 subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
 authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
 crlDistributionPoints = @crl_section
 authorityInfoAccess = @ocsp_section
 subjectAltName  = @alt_names

 [alt_names]
 DNS.0 = *.example.com
 DNS.1 = *.example1.com
 DNS.2 = example.com
 DNS.3 = example1.com
 IP.0 = 192.168.0.2
 IP.1 = 192.168.0.3
 IP.2 = 192.168.0.4
 IP.3 = 192.168.0.5
 IP.4 = 192.168.0.6
 IP.5 = 192.168.0.7

 [crl_section]
 URI.0 = http://pki.example.com/Example Intermediate Certificate Authority.crl

 [ocsp_section]
 OCSP;URI.0 = http://pki.example.com/ocsp/
 caIssuers;URI.0 = http://pki.example.com/Example Intermediate Certificate Authority.crt
```

If the extensions have a standard order to be placed, is my above config correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions are unordered, so whatever order you prefer would be fine.

p.s. Does your organization own 4146 PEN number? As per IANA registry, this PEN number is owned by **GlobalSign** and you are not allowed to use it in certificate policies. And 2.23.140.1.2.2 is owned by CAB Forum, so you are not allowed to use this OID either.

Comment: I had asked. But that guy told me I am allowed. Let me link that

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244417/what-oid-should-you-use-for-your-own-organization-validation-ssl-certs

Comment: Steffen Ullrich said: *I have no idea what you want to achieve in the first place. OID are just a series of octets with a registered associated meaning. There are no restrictions on who can use these OID. The meaning should make sense though in the context used and the one reading the certificate need to actually check the value and behave accordingly. So it all depends on what you express at the end and who will interpret the certificate policies - which is unknown.*

Comment: That comment by Steffen Ulrich is not correct, you are not allowed to use them. Your organization must register their own PEN at IANA (free of charge) or ANSI (fees apply). https://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page